# Does npm unit-converts package work with https://unpkg.com

Tags: javascript, npm, unpkg

I'm facing problems importing npm package 'convert-units' with unpkg, I tried this :

```
<script src="unpkg.com/convert-units@2.3.4/lib/index.js"></script>
```

But it seems not to work

Comment: What is the console output?

Comment: It says that convert function is not defined

Comment: I'm so sorry bro, I don't see what's missing there, I don't like using unpkg unless it's the only way to go, but from the docs and my experience, I don't see the error. Convert function is declared there, I would recommend going for an npm apporach.

Answer (score 0):

I came with an idea, I can't see the whole code, but... Are you requesting this package `BEFORE` any other `JavaScript` that uses this function?

I mean, something like **this**:

```
<script src="unpkg.com/convert-units@2.3.4/lib/index.js"></script>
<script src="...ROUTE_TO_JAVASCRIPT"></script>
```

**Otherwise**, if you first use package functions and then import it, those functions would be `not defined`.

So, remember, **order matters in this scenario.**

If you did this, you need to **import the module** in every place that you use it:

```
var convert = require('convert-units')
```

Comment: Yes I'm respecting the order

Comment: This not necessary since I'm loading certain components using Universal Module Definition (UMD) files in tags, I'm using react component in PHP page, we need only to add cdn source through javascript tags

Comment: Okey, I get it, I won't be able to provide a solution without debugging it or with an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but I feel that it is related with the import. Because if you request that unpkg subpage, you'll get everything.